# How to wrap multiple spans into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, wrapall

I have a JS code that wraps all lines into a span. I know I'm suppose to use `wrapall` but don't have any idea on where to start. Now I'm trying to find a way to wrap each of those spans into a div but limit a total to 4 spans. So for example if I have 5 spans, how would I wrap 4 spans into a div and the last one into a div like so:

```
<div class="wrap">
 <span class="line_wrap"></span>
 <span class="line_wrap"></span>
 <span class="line_wrap"></span>
 <span class="line_wrap"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
 <span class="line_wrap"></span>
</div>
```

Working example:

```js
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
  var $cont = $('.content')

  var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
  
  for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
      text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
  }
  
  $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
  
  $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');
  
  var lineArray = [],
      lineIndex = 0,
      lineStart = true,
      lineEnd = false
  
      $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          var top = pos.top;
  
          if (lineStart) {
              lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
              lineStart = false;
  
          } else {
              var $next = $(this).next();
  
              if ($next.length) {
                  if ($next.position().top > top) {
                      lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                      lineIndex++;
                      lineStart = true
                  }
              } else {
                  lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
              }
          }
  
      });
  
  
  //console.log( lineArray)
  for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
      var start = lineArray[i][0],
          end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;
  
      /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
      if (!end) {
          $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
      } else {
          $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
      }
  
  };
});
```

```css
.line_wrap{ border-top: 1px solid green}
.message-contain {padding:35px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch.
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch.
      </div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(".emails .multi-items").each(function (i) {
  var $cont = $('.content')

  var text_arr = $cont.text().split(' ');
  
  for (i = 0; i < text_arr.length; i++) {
      text_arr[i] = '<span>' + text_arr[i] + ' </span>';
  }
  
  $cont.html(text_arr.join(''));
  
  $wordSpans = $cont.find('span');
  
  var lineArray = [],
      lineIndex = 0,
      lineStart = true,
      lineEnd = false
  
      $wordSpans.each(function(idx) {
          var pos = $(this).position();
          var top = pos.top;
  
          if (lineStart) {
              lineArray[lineIndex] = [idx];
              lineStart = false;
  
          } else {
              var $next = $(this).next();
  
              if ($next.length) {
                  if ($next.position().top > top) {
                      lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
                      lineIndex++;
                      lineStart = true
                  }
              } else {
                  lineArray[lineIndex].push(idx);
              }
          }
  
      });
  
 
  for (i = 0; i < lineArray.length; i++) {
      var start = lineArray[i][0],
          end = lineArray[i][1] + 1;
  
      /* no end value pushed to array if only one word last line*/
      if (!end) {
          $wordSpans.eq(start).wrap('<span class="line_wrap">')
      } else {
          $wordSpans.slice(start, end).wrapAll('<span class="line_wrap">');
      }
  
  };
  
  var line_wrap = $(".line_wrap");
  
  for(var i=-1; i<line_wrap.length; i=i+4) {
      $('.line_wrap:eq('+i+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-1)+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-2)+'), .line_wrap:eq('+(i-3)+')').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');
    
  }
});
```

```css
.line_wrap{ border-top: 1px solid green}
.message-contain {padding:35px 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emails">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <div class="message-contain">
      <div class="content">
          Lorem Khaled Ipsum is a major key to success. They will try to close the door on you, just open it. Watch your back, but more importantly when you get out the shower, dry your back, it’s a cold world out there. The other day the grass was brown, now it’s green because I ain’t give up. Never surrender. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch. I’m keeping it real with you, so what you going do is have lunch. Every chance I get, I water the plants, Lion! In life you have to take the trash out, if you have trash in your life, take it out, throw it away, get rid of it, major key. You do know, you do know that they don’t want you to have lunch.
      </div>
  </div>
</ul>
</div>
```

Additional below code added to your code

```
var line_wrap = $(".line_wrap");

for(var i=-1; i<line_wrap.length; i=i+4) {
  $('.line_wrap:eq('+i+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-1)+'),.line_wrap:eq('+(i-2)+'), .line_wrap:eq('+(i-3)+')').wrapAll('<div class="wrap">');

}
```

Get all the elements with class `line_wrap` and then loop through each element.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It does work but a problem occurred if there's more than one set of lines to split into a span. I've update my code in the question. First set works fine but the second set has leftover <spans> that's not wrapped. Thanks again.

Comment: @GregorySchultz it's wrapping the next set of span also, only the first few span is missing as those are not wrapped with `. line_wrap`. Please check you code will find some answer in it.

Comment: Hey again, that problem is solved. Had an older version and didn't used the updated one. But a new problem has occurred. It double wraps all the spans, like this: `<div class="wrap"><div class="wrap"><span class="line_wrap"></span><span class="line_wrap"></span><span class="line_wrap"></span><span class="line_wrap"></span></div></div>`. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/openbayou/pen/qBdJrvw

Comment: Through an inspector, you can see it. View in full - https://imgur.com/a/AzNuva8

Comment: @GregorySchultz https://imgur.com/a/JJy4Qxy Please check I'n unable to see double wrap

Comment: I'm stumped. Shows it double wrapped on Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Hi again, I tried to do more than 4 and it messes up the code, it takes `.line_wrap` from another element and adds them to the first element, creating duplicate words. Anyway on how to solve it?